# Google Chrome Rendering Fonts Incorrectly

Tags: css, google-chrome, text, fonts, rendering

I don't even know how to properly identify what the issue is here, but my Google Chrome isn't rendering fonts properly.  At least not Helvetica, anyways.  Taking a screenshot is the only proper way I can explain what's happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG5Jh.jpg

This happens with nearly every website, but only in my Chrome.  I have no clue how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: It didn't fix the issue, but I managed to uninstall 'Helvetica Neue' and now fonts appear properly...

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem with the font Helvetica that you have in your system. Just uninstall that font.

Comment: You may please elaborate your answers, perhaps include some evidences and links to some authoritative sources. see [answer]